# Function to check if R function relies on C/C++ compiled code?

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp

I was wondering if there is any automated way in which one could check if an R function in a given package relies on C/C++ compiled code for most of it's execution or if instead it's implemented in pure R? I could of course look at the source code myself and see how it's implemented, but what I am looking for would be something like

```
iscompiled(somepackage::fun)
TRUE
```

in case function `fun()` in package `somepackage` was using compiled C/C++ code under the hood as opposed to being implemented in pure R. I guess one could check the overall dependency of a package on `Rcpp`, but this still wouldn't say anything about the reliance of individual functions in that package on C/C++. I know of course that most of the base R functions already use compiled C/C++ code, that's not my point... Any thoughts? Checking for the occurrence of `.C`, `.Call` or `sourceCpp` in the source code of that function?

Comment: Don't know R, but either it is written (partly) in C or eventually calls C functions from the standard library at some stage, or syscalls. As all OS have C code, **every** R program relies on C code. So what is your point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the function is `f` then this will be TRUE if `f` *directly* calls C/C++ or Fortran code.  It searches for the `invocation in the function's body:

```
any(grepl("\\b\\.(Call|Primitive|Internal|External|C|Fortran)\\b", body(match.fun(f))))
```

Note that if `f` *indirectly* calls such code, e.g., `f` calls `g` which in turn has the invocation then the above will return FALSE for `f` but TRUE for `g`.  Similarly if `f` is an S3 generic which in turn invokes specific methods and a method performs the invocation then the above will return FALSE for `f` but TRUE for any method f.X which directly invokes C/C++ or Fortran.

Comment: Many thanks! That's the kind of thing I was looking for! Indirect calls indeed would be harder to track down.... Regular expression could best be adapted I guess to look for either ".C(", ".Call(", "cxxfunction(" or "cfunction(".

Comment: You should also check for .Primitive, .Internal and .C.

Comment: If @TomWenseleers wants to make this a function that takes a character argument he'll have to mod this a bit.

Comment: also, prbly shld escape the `.` since this will affirm `tst <- function() { aCall("hello") }` is compiled when it's not

Comment: Some improvements made including some mentioned in comments.

Comment: Some packages (e.g. `grid`) call compiled code through their own `.Call` wrappers, e.g. `grid:::grid.Call()`.

Comment: We could either add `grid.Call` to the regular expression or just realize that we are in the situation where `g` is `grid.Call` and the limitation mentioned applies.